# SCR gate drive options when optotriacs not suitable due to high voltage of 1600V

Tags: circuit-design, high-voltage, opto-isolator, thyristor

I am designing a 3-phase circuit to switch 1kV 50kW using thyristor pairs.

The circuit is simple on/off switch, and needs to be simple as possible. I thought this precludes the  use of pulse transformers, as there is no zero-crossing information available.

It is essential also to use common parts, and optotriacs above 800V isolation seem to be unavailable.

The rough circuit so far looks like this. A transformer provides power so that a phototransistor (with 13kV isolation) can switch the gate. The transistor only sees the transformer voltage so is fine with its 32V rating.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQDqpN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The circuit looks very clumsy, so I wondered whether I was missing something. Also this circuit would constantly provide voltage to the gate even after the SCR1 has latched, and I am not sure if that is a problem or not.

Any comments on it or better options?

The circuit is simplified- it would be repeated 6 times as there are 6 SCRs in total.
SCR1 is used to switch the gate current to the SCR2 as the opto cannot switch the current- I am not sure how sensible this is.

Comment: Transformers can be used: simply gate a square wave into it.

Comment: Thanks Tim, do you mean a higher frequency square wave to a pulse transformer, so that it is irrelevant when the pulse occurs relative to zero crossing as the loss of waveform is tiny, i.e. a 1kHz wave?

Comment: The important observation is that, for non-GTO types (and even then..!), moderate reverse gate current has no impact on conduction, at least at nominal load currents. So just wire it direct to the transformer and drive it with a frequency higher than the load, say, comparable to 1/t_q. We use a gated pulse train rather than a single pulse, so that we don't care what the actual load current phase is, relative to the gate rising edge: if it were reverse biased when pulsed, the pulse would simply be ignored.

Comment: Hello Tim, if you put this as an answer, I will accept it, as this is what we went for in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transformer drive is a feasible alternative.

The key insight is that, for non-GTO types*, no amount of gate current, positive or negative (while respecting limits) will cause it to turn off, at least above some minimum load current (which is probably comparable to the gate current so delivered).

*And even then, GTO (Gate Turn-Off) operation requires sinking approximately the full load current out of the gate pin, with suitable (GTO type) devices; easily avoided here by adding some resistance in series with the transformer winding.

At light loads, it's tricky, because the h<sub>FE</sub> of the compound transistor equivalent is low at low currents; SCRs near or below holding current behave much like BJTs.  (Which, by the way, hints that gate voltage is normally ~0.7V when turned on and carrying load current -- another reason to use a current-limiting gate resistor, prevent backflow.)

Edge cases aside, for most load conditions, a tone burst, or gated pulse train, works just fine.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f10Fbw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We might use a circuit like this, for interface to a logic-level signal source (perhaps 74HC family gates, perhaps an MCU, whatever).  An NPN or NMOS could be used; or even PNP/PMOS if VCC is also logic VDD.  An R+C across the primary, or peak voltage clamp, may be desirable to handle leakage inductance; the transformer phasing should be as shown, so that forward conduction gives gate conduction (limited by VCC, turns ratio, and R1); D1 may also want some series resistance, to permit more reset voltage on the transformer (alternately, it could be omitted, relying on R2+C1 and the gate's reverse recovery (or lack thereof while conducting) via R1 to reset the transformer's flux.

Note the transformer should be designed to handle about 1V / R1 bias current on the secondary, before saturation; or heck, maybe saturation doesn't even matter (once it's on, who cares what the transformer is doing?).  In that case, perhaps a current-limiting resistor in series with the primary would be a good idea.

Or we might consider more elaborated gate drive networks, like a DC restorer / charge pump (avoids reverse-biasing the gate at all, ensuring continuous operation below holding current).

As for drive frequency, some to tens of kHz will suffice.  It should probably be below 1/t<sub>q</sub>, but even that might not be a big deal.

Further reading: 
[Triggering and Gate Characteristics of Thyristors - Teccor Electronics](https://m.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/electronics_technical/application_notes/switching_thyristor/littelfuse_triggering_and_gate_characteristics_of_thyristors_application_note.pdf) 
In particular, pages 58-60 and 66.  Not so much the schematic in particular (the age of this document is just dripping off the UJTs*), but the visual reference of triggering an SCR with a gated pulse train.  And the rest is generally applicable and may be found interesting and useful, as well as other application notes on Littelfuse's website (among other manufacturers').

*Historical aside:

I'm actually a little bit perplexed by this document; it seems to have vector graphics, but raster fonts; and content that would be relevant from the 1970s!  I wonder if it was updated/translated into electronic form over the years.  PDF was certainly a reliable, if new, format as of its 1998 (file?) creation date; it's possible it was PS, TeX (doubtful), troff (even more doubtful..?), or some proprietary (publisher specific) electronic format before then.

Which, by the way, isn't to say the information itself is outdated; SCRs have changed very little over the last half-century, the information is great.  I'm just remarking on the document's design, structure and formatting.

It is, of course, the property of Littelfuse now; they acquired Teccor way back in 2003.  Seems they never updated this document to reflect the change; it wouldn't have even been old at the time, i.e. sources most likely available and all that.  A little surprising.  But then, they have much the same content in other appnotes, which were updated for the new template; maybe this one is largely forgotten, but still available for download.  Who knows...

Ah well, one of those quirky things, both of early/ongoing electronic formats, and companies' use thereof.

Comment: Thank you Tim for all the extra details here about the practical side of using the transformer and the link to the Teccor document. The document goes into more detail on this subject than I have seen elsewhere so is a good read for me and others reading this answer. I especially like the comment about where you say that once the transformer gets the thyristor on we don't care about what it does (as long it is ready next time we need it). I like that. Thanks again.