What is the purpose of the Capacitor in this SCR trigger circuit?
I've seen this schematic for triggering an SCR. What is the purpose of the R2 and C1 in parallel with the primary winding? Is it just for back-emf? Why not use a diode? How do you calculate proper values for R2 and C1?

Schematic source: Answer to "SCR gate drive options when optotriacs not suitable due to high voltage of 1600V" by Tim Williams, posted on Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange, licensed under CC BY-SA 4.0

I've seen this schematic ... would you mind telling us where you have seen this schematic?

It's actually from another post on this forum. But I saw it again in a schematic at work and wanted to know more about it. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/686080/scr-gate-drive-options-when-optotriacs-not-suitable-due-to-high-voltage-of-1600v

@ThomasC. - Hi, FYI I have added the reference which site rules require from you, and used the format for material copied from Stack Exchange which is explained here. Copying from elsewhere on Stack Exchange, where material is licensed under a CC BY-SA license (currently version 4.0 but that differs at different times), imposes extra obligations on you e.g. mentioning and linking to that license - see the link I supplied. TY

Why didn't you just post a comment on @TimWilliams answer to get a direct explanation from him, rather than (what comes across as) asking everyone but him? He posted the circuit you show so I'd have though he'd be the first person you'd ask.

It was a while ago, I assumed it was a dead thread.

@ThomasC. Threads don't die on this forum.

In fact I'm still active here and have now seen this -- but new postings are unreliable as readers may not click based on the title, or questions run off the end of the feed and go missed. The only reliable communication is commenting directly, or, I think, moderator contact. Anyway, a reason was given: "An R+C across the primary, or peak voltage clamp, may be desirable to handle leakage inductance" -- what does this suggest about choice of RC values? What about the transformer value (inductance and ratio), what role would that play in the circuit?

ThomasC, now you and @TimWilliams have this comment enquiry, you should continue it on that other answer, not here. Future readers of that question/answer can then benefit from the discussion/explanations you're doing now and any answer update that might come out of it. It's useless to them doing that here. This question can be closed.

Does this answer your question? SCR gate drive options when optotriacs not suitable due to high voltage of 1600V

I don't mind this question as-is, it's not a question asked by the referenced thread, nor answered in particular detail there -- but it would be better to formulate it around its own subject. The R+C is a "snubber network"; when would we use snubbers on switching transformers? Given these terms, you may find there are existing questions that better answer it, or that it is a novel question that should indeed proceed.
